# Trying to add Image background to launchscreen.storyboard; constraint issue?

Tags: ios, launch-screen

Currently building an app in swift.
I am trying to add a background image behind the Label containing title of my app, on the launchscreen.storyboard
But when I launch the sim, I get a blank screen.

I have tried setting top, left, bottom and right constraints for the ImageView to 0 and setting the appropriate constraints for title Label.
When I do that, I get the following message:
[Constraint Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoFOW.png)

I've keep trying to move things around and try different constraints, etc, but I am at a loss..

**EDIT:**
I have solved my issue! Huzzah!

Comment: You do know that `lauchscreen.storyboard` is not capable of processing code, right?

Comment: Also, if you have a blank project it may start instantly and you may not notice the launch screen.

Comment: Can you show some more of your constraints?

Comment: ​That is actually really helpful information for future reference.
I had no idea that you couldn't use code in the launchscreen!
But I wasn't trying to use any code in the launchscreen.storyboard.
I actually resolved my issue!
I found out through some tinkering, that that wasn't the issue!

For some reason the images weren't set to appear in the app.

When I changed that setting, voila! images! in my app!
:D
Thanks for looking into my problem for me.
I very much appreciate it.
I actually really love this place. It's helped me quite a lot.